# Could you answer this: int a[][] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} }; What is the value of a[1][2] java

Tags: java

I have been attempting to answer this: Could somebody clarify and help me understand what is going on with this problem 
Thank You!

Comment: Please put the code in the body of your post, not your title.

Comment: This is best answered by going through a basic [array tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: I have looked through numerous array tutorials but this specific scenario is not answered there.

Comment: Layman terms: get the 3rd value `[2]` of the 2nd array `[1]` from the multidimensional array  `a`

Comment: so how would the final product appear-would it be - a[2][6]?

Comment: Try it and see. BTW, the output will be `6`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner and unsure of certain basic things, it is good to write a program and infer the results. It will also helps you to understand as well as code efficiently. a[1][2] is 6

Here is your sample program:

```
public class Program{

 public static void main(String []args){

    int a[][] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} }; 

    for(int i =0;i<2;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            System.out.println("Array["+i+"]["+j+"] = "+ a[i][j]);
        }
    }
 }
 }
```